# Is it possible to make mqtt webpage without websocket?

Tags: mqtt

I am trying to build a simple webpage that connects to a mqtt broker and updates some information. Is it possible to do it with pure mqtt instead of a websocket and if it is, is it safer or better?

Answer (score 0):

If you want direct page to broker communication then MQTT over WebSockets is the only option.

The sandbox in the browser will ONLY allow HTTP or WebSocket connections.